# What Query To be Used For getting the output has given below on the table given?

Tags: mysql

The database is

```
+---+-----+------+------------+
| x | y   | z    | d          |
+---+-----+------+------------+
| 1 | abc | you  | 2016-07-11 |
| 1 | ac  | you  | 2016-07-12 |
| 2 | boo | game | 2016-07-13 |
| 2 | boo | hoho | 2016-07-14 |
| 2 | foo | game | 2016-07-21 |
| 2 | goo | gzz  | 2016-07-31 |
| 3 | gaa | bha  | 2016-07-05 |
+---+-----+------+------------+
```

I want the output has

```
------------------------------
|  x  |  y  |  z  |      d   |
------------------------------
|  1  | ac  | you |2016-07-12|
|  2  | foo | game|2016-07-21|
|  3  | gaa | bha |2016-07-05|
------------------------------
```

What is the query for this I am newbie in mysql. Please help me out with it. Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the logic behind the query?

Comment: Logic as well as the query

Comment: select * from xyz x1 where x1.x = (select distinct x from xyz where d = (select max(d) from xyz)) ;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to select the record for each value of `x` which has the latest date in column `d`.  If so, then the following query should work:

```
SELECT t1.x, t1.y, t1.z, t1.d
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT x, MAX(d) AS d
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY x
) t2
    ON t1.x = t2.x AND t1.d = t2.d
```